# Upgrading to SDL Tridion 8.5. Does anyone know what this might indicate when calling the odata service?

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion

> Oct 19, 2018 8:08:50 PM CDT Info  com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AbstractAmbientDataServletFilter BEA-000000  Requested by IP: (server_name / port)
>
> Oct 19, 2018 8:08:50 PM CDT  Info com.sdl.web.content.claimprocessor.WritableODataClaimProcessor BEA-000000  No session wrapper is installed, not allowing modification operations
>
> Oct 19, 2018 8:08:50 PM CDT Error
> com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataRendererActor BEA-000000

```
Invalid request - com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: '`?' expected but `P' found'
com.sdl.odata.api.parser.ODataUriParseException: `?' expected but `P' found
at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataUriParser.parseUri(ODataUriParser.scala:34)
at com.sdl.odata.parser.ODataParserImpl.parseUri(ODataParserImpl.java:37)
at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(ODataParserActor.scala:34)
at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:480)
at com.sdl.odata.service.actor.ODataParserActor.aroundReceive(ODataParserActor.scala:27)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Hello brian and welcome to the Tridion StackExchange. In order for us to better understand what the issue is and thus increasing the chance of you getting helpful answers and tips, please edit your question and include additional details like: how are you calling the service, what is the exact query, which causes this error, relevant log files, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you it can't parse the URI. To analyse this, you need to find out what URI it's trying to parse. Try looking in the logs for the URI (if necessary put the logging into DEBUG mode). Failing that, put a proxy between the client and server to look at the traffic between the two.

The next question is why the URI isn't correctly formed. You can double-check all your configuration files to see if there are any errors there.